# Schema in Pig after Flattening the String

Tags: schema, apache-pig, flatten

I am having the problem in implementing the field object ( schema) after flatting the string in pig.  I have the following code:

Data = load 'data/*.txt' using PigStorage( ) AS(...., date:chararray, .....);

B = foreach Data FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(date, '"(.*)/(.*)/(.*)

(.*):(.*):(.*)"')) AS (month:int, day:int, year:int, hour:int, min:int, second:int);

--B = filter B by year==2015;

--B = filter B by month ==1 OR month ==2;

C = foreach B generate speed, month, day, year, hour, min;

store C into 'data/out_files' using PigStorage(',');

Where date is in the form  ( '2/23/2015 23:56:49')

This works perfectly fine. But when I use filter in B ( year ==2015 or month ==1 OR  month ==2), this code does not work. Do you have a good idea  how to use any field after flattening String?. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

**input:**

```
2/23/2015 23:56:49
1/23/2014 23:56:49
9/23/2014 23:56:49
8/23/2014 23:56:49
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (date:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(date, '([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\\s+([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)')) AS (month,day,year,hour,min,second);
C = FILTER B BY (month==1) OR (month==2) OR (year==2015);
D = FOREACH C GENERATE month,day,year,hour,min,second;
DUMP D;
```

**Output:**

```
(2,23,2015,23,56,49)
(1,23,2014,23,56,49)
```

The below Regex also works.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(date, '(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)')) AS (month,day,year,hour,min,second);
```

Comment: Thank you Sivasakthi ,  still I am getting error, Cannot cast bytearray to int. This is due to C = FILTER B BY year==2015. When i changed year as int, still got the same previous error.

Comment: By default, pig will convert bytearray to int as part of implicit typecast, so this should work.  I didn't face any issue in the above script and both the filter statements that you mentioned are working fine for me. Can you close your terminal, open it again and rerun the script?. (I used Pig 0.13 version.)